# Harvard Software Referencing using NatBib

Tags: natbib

I'm new to using latex and have had a pretty easy time referencing everything as it should using natbib. The only issue is that my referencing guide requires a specific format for software. I'm currently trying to reference a game and it should be in this format (I'm referencing Sea of Thieves so I will use that)

```
Rare (2018) *Sea of Thieves* [game]. (Place of Publication): Xbox
Games Studios. Available from https://store.steampowered.com/app/1172620/ 
[accessed 6 November 2022]
```

I should also add I am not 100% sure what to put as the Place of Publication but have just included it in word form here
However whenver I use @software (I'm not sure if this exists in the package that I am using) it returns just

```
Rare (2018), *Sea of Thieves*
```

Which is not my desired output my bibtex file looks like this

```
@software{seaofthieves,
    author={Rare},
    year={2018},
    title={Sea of Thieves},
    type={game},
    publisher={Xbox Games Studios}
}
```

I don't have some of the stuff in there however I am just struggling to get it all to appear correctly. It also crashes whenever I use the url field. I wasn't sure if there was a workaround to allow me to display it how I want.
And I'm also not sure if this is something that would be fixed if I used a different package like biblatex for example. But I found natbib was easy to use for harvard referencing so decided to use it
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `natbib` is mainly a citation management system, and  it therefore does not directly determine how the typeset entries are formatted. That's really the job of the bibliography style that's in use. Hence, do please tell us which bibliography style you employ. (Hint: the bibliography style that's in use is the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` directive.)

Comment: I see I completely forgot to include that. I am using the agsm style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `agsm` bib style does not recognize `@software` as a valid entry type and will therefore fall back on the `@misc` entry.

I suggest you try something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@software{seaofthieves,
    author={Rare},
    year={2018},
    title={Sea of Thieves [game]},
    type={game},
    howpublished={(Place of Publication): Xbox Games Studios},
    note = {Available from \url{https://store.steampowered.com/app/1172620/} 
[accessed 6 November 2022]},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It works perfectly